# Angular js - How to read query string value of the URL that is opened by $window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular JS. I am gradually learning it and finding it interesting.

I have a "Login" html page and a "Home" html page. "Home" html page displays navigation menu that open up other html pages.

Same ***ng-app*** and ***ng-controller*** (see below code) are declared in both "Login" html page and "Home" html page. (Both are using same angular module js.)

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoAppModule" ng-controller="DemoAppController">
```

I am opening up "Home" html page when user is successfully authenticated in Login controller (js).

To open the "Home" html page I am using $window.open() in Login controller (js). 
I am passing the loginid as query string (see below code) along with the "Home" html URL.

```
$window.open("http://localhost:8083/home.html?loginid=" + loginid, "_self");
```

How to retrieve the loginid from query string in the Home controller js?

Comment: did you try using window.location to fetch the url then extract loginid from it

Comment: share more code related to controller of home.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `Home-controller.js`

try doing

`var url = new URL(window.location.toString());
 var loginId = url.searchParams.get("loginid");//metion your search param name as is in url`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angularjs you can make use of $location or $window services.

```
function homeController($scope, $location) {

   console.log($location.search().loginid);
}
```

Comment: Console log shows "undefined".
The solution given below worked for me.

Comment: Oh okay :) There might be some issue, Here is the working demo - http://embed.plnkr.co/KzcMJmDGfN263AQrVY9N/